# Extracting Matches from Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Given a string

```
""Being Ordered Around by You Makes Me Really Angry Somehow!!!" "Whaddaya Mean, 'Somehow'!!?""
""Omae ni Meirei Sareru no wa Nanka Haratatsu!!!" "Nankatte Nani!!?""
```

How can I extract the string between each set of double quotes (including double quotes in between) so that I get two separate strings like:

```
"Being Ordered Around by You Makes Me Really Angry Somehow!!!" "Whaddaya Mean, 'Somehow'!!?"
```

and

```
"Omae ni Meirei Sareru no wa Nanka Haratatsu!!!" "Nankatte Nani!!?"
```

The regex I'm currently using is `"(.*)(.*)"` and it matches okay according to this tool

[image]

My problem is extracting the two matches as seperate strings.

```
var pattern =  new Regex(@"""(.*)(.*)""", RegexOptions.None);
var matches = pattern.Matches(text);
```

`matches` doesn't contain two elements. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somthing like [`(?<=")".*?"(?=")`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yktEVu)?

Comment: If you wan't to extract the two groups, use `Regex.Match` to get a `Match` object, that contains the two `Groups` you're after (1 and 2).

Comment: And an explanation to your regex: since `.` matches any character **but** `new line`, you get two capture groups, separated by a `new line`, and ending with a `new line`, i.e. the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Regex.Match` instead of `Matches`, and this regex

```
"("[^"]*")[^"]*("[^"]*")"
```

It matches a `"`, **captures** a following `"` and anything up to, and including,  the next `"`. Then it matches anything up to the next `"`. Then it repeats - **captures** the following `"` and anything up to, and including,  the next `"`. Finally it matches the terminating `"`. The two strings, including their surrounding quotes are in capture group 1 & 2.

Something like this:

```
    string s1 = "\"\"Being Ordered Around by You Makes Me Really Angry Somehow!!!\" \"Whaddaya Mean, 'Somehow'!!?\"\"",
           s2 = "\"\"Omae ni Meirei Sareru no wa Nanka Haratatsu!!!\" \"Nankatte Nani!!?\"\"";

    Console.WriteLine("Before 1  : " + s1);
    Console.WriteLine("Before 2  : " + s2);

    Regex r = new Regex("\"(\"[^\"]*\")[^\"]*(\"[^\"]*\")\"");
    Match m = r.Match(s1);
    Console.WriteLine("After 1.1 : " + m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("After 1.2 : " + m.Groups[2].Value);

    m = r.Match(s2);
    Console.WriteLine("After 2.1 : " + m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("After 2.2 : " + m.Groups[2].Value);
```

[See it here at ideone](https://ideone.com/siPjmT).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what OP was looking for. OP has only one input string and is looking for the two strings that are between two quotation marks.

Comment: @Verarind That was my first thought as well. But since the two strings already are on separate lines, I gathered this was what the OP wanted. But I'm not sure either...

Comment: the raw text comes as one line separated by a new line character.

Comment: what I want is  `var a = "\"Being Ordered Around by You Makes Me Really Angry Somehow!!!" "Whaddaya Mean, 'Somehow'!!?"\"` and `var b = "\"Omae ni Meirei Sareru no wa Nanka Haratatsu!!!" "Nankatte Nani!!?\""`

Comment: OK. That's what my answer gives you. Is there another problem?

Comment: @lxkmxl I'm pretty sure that your comment _the raw text comes as one line separated..._ should be _...as one **string** separated..._, should it? _one line separated by a new line_ doesn't make sense. If I'm right you can use my comment to your original post to do that. If I'm wrong ClasG gave you the answer you needed. In both cases I think our job is done and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/lF1zI5/1)

```
("{2}.+?"{2})
```

and iterate on matches provided by [MatchCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.